# How to extend the range that is included in a graph with a macro

Tags: excel, vba, graph

I have some data in **column A** and am trying to write a macro to extend the data range to the next - column B, so that every time I add data in following columns, the macro will extend the border to include that data in the graph plot.

See image below where only column A is included in my graph -
[image]

What do I need to do in order to get it to also include the next column - column B

For example:

[image]

What do you think?

Comment: Try putting your data in a table (insert>table) and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: How are the values in the columns populated, manually, by VBA or by formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Sub ExpandChartSource()
    
    Dim ObjChart As Object
    Dim RngSource As Range
    
    Set ObjChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    
    Set RngSource = Range(Split(ObjChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula, ",")(2))
    
    Set RngSource = RngSource.Resize(RngSource.Rows.Count, RngSource.Columns.Count + 1)
    
    ObjChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=RngSource
    
End Sub
```

Here a more dynamic version, useful if you want to enlarge the data indefinitely:

```
Sub ExpandChartSource()
    
    Dim ObjChart As Object
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim IntSeries As Integer
    Dim StrAddress As String
    
    Set ObjChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    
    Set RngSource = Range(Split(ObjChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula, ",")(2))
    StrAddress = RngSource.Cells(1, 1).Address
    
    Set RngSource = Range(Split(ObjChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(ObjChart.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count).Formula, ",")(2))
    StrAddress = StrAddress & ":" & RngSource.Cells(RngSource.Rows.Count, 1).Address
    
    Set RngSource = Range(StrAddress)
    
    Set RngSource = RngSource.Resize(RngSource.Rows.Count, RngSource.Columns.Count + 1)
            
    ObjChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=RngSource
    
End Sub
```

It assumes that the first series is the one most on the left while the last series is assumed to be on the right.

Comment: thats awesome, thank you, that did exactly what I wanted.